# FileProvider for specific file path in honor device

Tags: android, uri, filepath, android-fileprovider

I am not able to find Uri for below file. I am using Honor device

**filepath**: `/data/hw_init/product/region_comm/oversea/media/Pre-loaded/Music/Magic_Mullet.mp3`

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.abc.xyz.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>


fun getFileUri(context: Context?, file: File): Uri? {
        var uri: Uri? = null
        try {
            if (context != null) {
                uri = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.abc.xyz.provider", file)
                } else {
                    Uri.fromFile(file)
                }
            }
        } catch (ex: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException) {
            uri = null
        }
        return uri
}
```

I am able to get internal storage path Uri's but how to get file path which starts `/data/hw_init`?

Answer (score 1):

`FileProvider` does not support serving files from arbitrary locations, such as that one. You need to create your own `ContentProvider` that works a bit like `FileProvider`, where you serve the file from your desired location.

Comment: OK. Can you suggest me any reference for same?

Comment: @Nik: [This sample is old](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v8.7/ContentProvider/Files/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/cp/files/FileProvider.java) but demonstrates the basic technique. In my case, the file happens to be in `getFilesDir()`, but that is not essential. That sample is covered in [this free edition of one of my books](https://commonsware.com/Android/Android-8.7-CC.pdf).

Comment: OK let me check.